# How to set "Follow Action" in thirtytwos? (Ableton Live)

Tags: ableton, ableton-live

When trying to set "follow action" to next loop, there isn't an input field for thirtytwos.

(Time signature is 4/4, grid is 1/32)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a small research, I don't think Ableton Live "want" you to loop by these measures,

(checked on both live 8.0 & 9.0,
left a message on their boards, will update any further info)

Comment: From ableton boards - "Regardless of grid size the follow actions can only be precise down to 1/4's of a beat...."